# Sending choice field as e-mail subject

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a choice field like this in my forms.py:

```
ASSUNTO = ( ('1', u'Informações'), 
        ('2', 'Comercial'), 
        ('3', 'Financeiro'), 
        ('4', 'Outro'))
```

In my views.py when I send the chosen value from the choice field as e-mail subject, it comes like:

Chose '**Comercial**' in my form in my html page

E-mail received with subject like: '**2 - MY COMPANY**'

Code in my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import FormContato
from django.core.mail import send_mail


def HomeContato(request):
    form = FormContato()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormContato(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send_mail( form.cleaned_data['assunto'] + ' - MY COMPANY', 'Nome: ' + form.data['nome'] + ' ' + form.data['sobrenome'] + ' :: ' + 'E-mail: ' + form.data['email'] + ' :: ' + 'Mensagem: ' + form.data['menssagem'], 'noreply@email.com.br', ['email@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
            return render(request, 'contato/contato.html', locals())
        else:
            return render(request, 'contato/contato.html', locals())
    else:
        return render(request, 'contato/contato.html', locals())
```

How can I use this command getting the subject as: 'Comercial - MY COMPANY'?

Thanks in advance to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isnt very pretty, but the following should do it:

```
{choice[0]:choice[1] for choice in form.fields['assunto'].choices}[form.cleaned_data['assunto']]
```

**NOTE:** after reading the other answer, you could do `dict(form.fields['assunto'].choices)[form.cleaned_data['assunto']]` - I didnt think to use a builtin function instead of a comprehension

Also the reason you are getting "2" is that the choices tuple is a tuple of value => label tuples.

if you want the value to not be a meaningless integer, make it like this:

```
ASSUNTO = ( (u'Informações', u'Informações'), 
    ('Comercial', 'Comercial'), 
    ('Financeiro', 'Financeiro'), 
    ('Outro', 'Outro'))
```

and then keep your view the same as you currently have it

Comment: To change the tuple to a meaningful name solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem. I wasnt sure if you had to work with the tuple as it was, because of some other requirement. So I offered both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
dict(ASSUNTO)[form.cleaned_data['assunto']] + ...
```

Comment: Yes, I am receiving the e-mail in my inbox.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include your entire view function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mis-read what value you were trying to retrieve. I'll revise my answer for you.

Comment: How can I use this dict(ASSUNTO) if this "ASSUNTO" is in my forms.py file?

Comment: Just import it into your view: from your_app.forms import ASSUNTO

Comment: Thanks for your help Brandon. The easiest way was to do what Francis pointed and changed my tuple with meaningful names. Thanks for you time and effort.